# xorg.conf: how to automatically update VendorName and ModelName in Monitor section?

Tags: xorg, xorg.conf

`Xorg -configure` generates xorg.conf but does not fill out these fields properly though it should. Are there any measures to correct them without manual editing?

Answer (score 0):

`nvidia-settings` does it. When done `X Server Display Configuration` then click `Save to X Configuration File` and merge with your existing `xorg.conf`. Your monitor model will be updated as well as video-card model.

[image]